# What determines the leaderboard ranking order for Arrange mode?

Tags: steam, mushihimesama

Some months ago, I took a look at the Mushihimesama Steam leaderboard for Arrange mode. I noticed that the rank 2 player has a better score than the rank 1 player, as you can see at this screenshot:

[image: mushihimesama steam leaderboard arrange mode]

My question is, why? Is it just a bug or is the score not the only reason to get a higher rank?

Comment: Maybe, given how sloppy looking that UI looks it wouldn't surprise me if it was a bug.

Comment: @Angzuril Thanks for creating the mushihimesama tag, I don't have enough reputation to create it :'(